# Unload kernel-module before boot

Tags: boot, kernel, boot-failure, ndiswrapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

I compiled Ndiswrapper from source. Then installed a wireless windows driver. After that I loaded the Ndiswrapper kernel-module with `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`. Now my system stops during boot.

How can I unload the Ndiswrapper kernel-module?

Comment: Does your systems completely stop at boot? Can you go to the recovery mode?

Comment: @Anwar I tried recovery mode, but it stops too.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/110349/61218) to disable `ndiswrapper` module temporarily and see the above link to disable it permanently once you get into the system

Comment: @Anwar thx adding `ndiswrapper.blacklist=yes` as [boot parameter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-boot-parameter) solved my problem, but it's not necessary to do that permanently. My intention was, how can I do that before boot. On a running system I know how to blacklist a kernel-modul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot using a Live USB and modify the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file.

Just add the module you don't want to load, e.g.

```
blacklist ieee1394
blacklist ohci1394
blacklist eth1394
blacklist sbp2
```

You can also blacklist modules from the bootloader.

Simply add `modprobe.blacklist=modname1,modname2,modname3` to your bootloader's kernel-line parameter list.

For information on how to edit the boot parameters, go here: [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/q/19486/83046).

Comment: Instead of `ndiswrapper.blacklist=yes`, I could also use `modprobe.blacklist=ndiswrapper`?

Comment: yes, you can use it.