# How can I temporarily disable a kernel module?

Tags: kernel

I would like to temporarily (until next boot) disable a kernel module.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not trying to blacklist it. I just want to remove it until I reboot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `lsmod` to find the name of a kernel module about that you are interested in temporarily disabling. After you've found the name, use this command to disable the module:

```
sudo modprobe -r <module_name>
```

However, this command will fail with an error message something like `FATAL: Module <module_name> is in use` if a process is using:

- the `<module_name>`
- a module about that `<module_name>` directly depends on
- any module about that `<module_name>` - through the dependency tree - depends on indirectly.

You can use `lsmod | grep <module_name>` to obtain the names of the modules which are preventing you from temporarily disabling a certain module (these module names are listed in the last column).

More about:

- http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Working_with_Kernel_Modules.html#sec-Listing_Currently-Loaded_Modules
- http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Unloading_a_Module.html

Comment: This doesn't however, disable or 'remove' buildin modules, which will give an `FATAL: Module g_serial is builtin.` error.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how to remove modules that are in use? What needs to be done after running the `lsmod` command?

Answer (score 4):

It appears:

```
sudo modprobe -r moduleName
```

Achieves what I want. The module is removed and reloaded upon reboot.

Comment: however, the module is reloaded if Linux thinks it's needed. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: In my case it's not what I want. I want to add the module to the blocklist temporarily