# AMD-V is being used by another hypervisor. (VERR_SVM_IN_USE)

Tags: virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

When I try to open any OS on Oracle VirtualBox an error accurate.

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine xp efendi.
AMD-V is being used by another hypervisor. (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).
VirtualBox can't enable the AMD-V extension. Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).
```

How can I repair this problem?

Comment: I can not find any solution on Internet for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is because you have virtualbox and kvm installed. The kernel modules conflict.

The "simple" solution is to use one or the other, but not both. You can, however, use both as long as you are willing to manually (or script) loading / unloading the kernel modules.

To see your modules

```
#Virtualbox modules
sudo lsmod | grep vbox

#kvm
sudo lsmod| grep kvm
```

To remove a module

```
# remove virtualbox
sudo rmmod vboxdrv
sudo rmmod vboxnetflt

#remove kvm
sudo rmmod kvm
sudo rmmod kvm_amd
```

use insmod

```
sudo insmod /full/path/to/your/modules
```

You can find the module with

```
locate kvm | grep .ko
locate vbox | grep .ko
```

Use the modules for your current kernel.

Answer (score 3):

This problem has solved by following codes in terminal:

```
sudo killall VBoxSVC
export VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE=true
VirtualBox
```

Comment: I ended up having to remove `kvm` and `kvm_amd`, [blacklist](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules) them, _and_ do this when I run my VM. But it's working now!

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster Thank you very much for sharing your solution. It is very easy and solves all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

For me, there was no kvm module loaded (lsmod | grep kvm, shows nothing), thus it was enough to simply set the VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE=true as Huseyin pointed out.

For my particular case when I was running virtualbox without sudo, my existing win 7 vdi was trapped in a recovery console screen. (every action eventually restarted my machine) Maybe some permission issues, (solved by running sudo virtualbox, however I'm not sure this is the recommended way)

Another great read about how to script your way into "Using KVM and VirtualBox side by side"
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/kvm-virtualbox.html

Comment: How can I would be able to set permenantly?

Comment: @Huseyin add it to your `.bash_profile` or somewhere else that gets run on login (make sure to `export`, not just set the var).

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem by closing Docker Desktop so be sure you have turned off docker or other virtualization technologies.

Comment: Closing Gnome "Boxes" (another VM client) worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

Run System Monitor, search for KVM and kill it.