# docker-desktop alongside VirtualBox - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: virtualbox, windows, 22.04, docker

I have **Ubuntu 22.04** installed in my desktop computer with an **AMD processor**, I've worked a lot with **docker-dekstop** in my machine without any problem.

I just recently installed **VirtualBox** in it and created a **Windows 11 virtual machine**. Everything went well until I realized **docker-desktop and VirtualBox can not run together at the same time** for some reason.

I have detected two different scenarios.

- If VirtualBox is playing the Windows 11 machine, when I open docker-desktop it never starts. I just get this message and it never passes this stage.

  [image: docker-starting]
- On the other hand, if docker-desktop was turned on before starting the virtual machine I get this error.

  [image: VERR_SVM_IN_USE-err]

I have already tried all of these solutions suggested in these two posts, but no luck so far:

- [docker-desktop stuck at - "Docker Desktop Starting... "](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415053/docker-desktop-stuck-at-docker-desktop-starting)
- [AMD-V is being used by another hypervisor. (VERR_SVM_IN_USE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403591/amd-v-is-being-used-by-another-hypervisor-verr-svm-in-use)

If it helps, I also have the **VirtualBox Extension Pack** installed:

[image: vbox-ext-pack]

Now, I'm just wondering why this is happening and if there is any chance to make this work or if it is simply impossible and whenever I want to use one of them I have to stop the other process.

Comment: As far as I've seen, Docker and VirtualBox do not play well together on *any* host operating system, not just Ubuntu. If the goal is to run Windows, it may be possible to do this inside a Docker container (I know that Win10 and earlier will run in a Docker container with RDP) 

Comment: Since, docker desktop uses Qemu so, [this post could be helpful to understand](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/10srsj6/how_do_i_run_qemukvm_and_virtualbox_at_the_same/) the problem better.

Comment: Same core issue here of Docker Desktop + VirtualBox cannot be started together successfully, on an Ubuntu 22.04 host, though I'm on Intel with no VirtualBox Extension Pack.