# How to prevent a module from being loaded

Tags: modprobe

So I have to use a command every time I boot my laptop in order to my wireless to work.

the command is:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
```

I found that this is a common type of question but I didn't find a pattern in the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to blacklist kernel modules?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you blacklist the module so it never loads at all:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and test.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a configuration file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`

## Blacklisting modules

In your case since you don't want to load acer-wmi module automatically, you have to blacklist it.

First try this command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo blacklist acer-wmi >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
```

In the case where the module is still being load, it means that there is another module that depends on acer-wmi. So a workaround is to use:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo install acer-wmi /bin/false >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
```

Sources: [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules), [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Using_files_in_.2Fetc.2Fmodprobe.d.2F_2)

**Edit:** Rectification according to chili555's answer.

Comment: so the -r is to remove the module?

Comment: Yes. From `man modprobe` command:
This option (-r or --remove) causes modprobe to remove rather than insert a module. If the modules it depends on are also unused, modprobe will try to remove them too.

Comment: the echo didn't work but since you explained what it was supposed to do, I manually added the 'blacklist acer-wmi' to the modprobe blacklist file thanks

I will also mark your answer as the correct, even if chili555 was right because you explained and you placed links to documentation.
kudos for both :)

Comment: @LeRieur The correct file is not /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it is /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.