# WiFi doesn't work in UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I used Windows but uninstalled it, and installed Ubuntu 16.04. Now I have a big problem: My WiFi stopped working. I tried everything I could find, and still no WiFi. for 10 days.

My machine is :

- Acer Aspire V13  / V3-371-55PF
- CPU Intel Core i5-4210U 1.7 GHz with Turbo Boost ut to 2.7 GHz
- Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adaptor (rev 01)
- Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe ath9k` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Was there no response at all to: `sudo modprobe ath9k`? Let's check for messages in the log: `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: sudo modprobe ath9k : no response

Comment: dmesg | grep ath
[   11.890800] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[   11.890802] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6a
[   11.890803] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   11.890804] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   11.890804] ath: Regpair used: 0x6a
[   12.138944] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   13.451621] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

Comment: I see the conection but I can't conect

Comment: How about: `dmesg | grep wlp` Does it connect if you power-cycle the router; i.e. unplug and replug?

Comment: No. Here is the result after  dmesg | grep https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B8pRyQLbNooFOMv0QphwUIXRqGsYUTawXmo_gyLXjGI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
exit
```

Comment: I don't have permission to change router's configuration.But with this router works 4 other machines. Second - I work with my machine at home, at work and  other places. Everywhere is same. Reg was 00, I changed it and  set it up permanently my country code. Set  Ipv6  to ignore. Set :-  ath9k nohwcrypt=1 . WiFi still doesn't work. I'm sorry.

Comment: The following answer doesn't help https://askubuntu.com/a/546970/498780 ?

Comment: @GAD3R The answer you linked is a suggestion to blacklist *acer-wmi* in order to correct a hard-block. In the readings Angel Trifonov gave us, there is no hard-block at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same laptop running ubuntu gnome 16.04, the wifi would connect to my home network but be completely unusable.
Within seconds of connecting I'd be getting 70-90% packet loss with pings in the 1000's ms, often dropping from that to timeouts and something like a buffer error.

The fix for me was disabling the 802.11'n' features on the card, the issue stopped straight away and the wifi hasn't had an issue for weeks now.

I believe this was the post I got it from, the iwlwifi part halfway down.
[How do I keep my Wifi from dropping out? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out)