# Disable USB hub

Tags: usb, 14.10

I wish to be able for security reasons to be able to disable all of my USB ports, to do this without having to do every USB port individually, I would have to disable my entire USB hub, so that really is my question, how would I go about disabling my USB hub?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10, and the command `lsusb` returns the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If you need for me to provide any more information to my question to help you answer it then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the entire USB hub so that no mice, keyboards, USB sticks whatever can be used, just do a:

```
lsmod | grep usb
```

and [blacklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules) all modules that contain `usb` in the first column.

I'm sorry?  Mice and stuff still need to work? Oh!  Only blacklist `usb_storage` then!

**;-)**

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible from BIOS. Another option is to write a `udev` rule to unbind any USB root hub driver: `ohci-pci` (USB 1.1), `ehci-pci` (USB 2.0) and `xhci_hcd` (USB 3.0).

1. Create new rules file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/90-disable-usb.rules
   ```
2. Add these rule lines

   ```
   DRIVERS=="?hci-pci", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k >/sys%p/driver/unbind'"
   DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k >/sys%p/driver/unbind'"
   ```
3. Reboot

**Notes:**

- Example how to check which driver and other device attributes to use them in `udev` rule:

  ```
  udevadm info --name=/dev/bus/usb/001/001 --attribute-walk
  ```

  or

  ```
  lsusb -t
  ```
- Depending on your hardware/platform. There are many USB host drivers. Check [Linux source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/usb/host?id=refs/tags/v3.18.7)