# Nvidia: Xorg crashes on 15.04: "drmSetMaster failed: Invalid argument"

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 15.04

## Nvidia: Xorg crashes on 15.04:  "drmSetMaster failed: Invalid argument"

On a clean install of Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, I get the following screen after installing the Nvidia proprietary driver:

```
starting version 219
[  OK  ] Started ACPI event daemon.
                    Starting ACPI event daemon...
_
```

The last few lines from Xorg.0.log:

```
<snip>
[     3.660] (II) intel(G0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     3.660] (II) intel(G0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[     3.660] (II) intel(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
[     3.660] (II) intel(G0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[     3.660] (II) intel(G0): hardware support for Present enabled   
[     3.660] (EE) modeset(G1): drmSetMaster failed: Invalid argument
[     3.660] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     3.660] (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for gpu driver 1 -1
<snip>
[     3.661] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

(complete log [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10873992/))

I tried all available proprietary Nvidia drivers.

System specifications:

- OS: Ubuntu GNOME 15.04
- CPU: Intel i5-3570K
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660

How can this error be resolved?

Comment: @ViliusK: Disabling the Intel GPU in the BIOS/UEFI results in a proper boot, as does booting trough recovery mode (because the intel driver doesn't work in that situation). It's kind of a workaround, but worked in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'solution' for me is disabling the Intel integrated GPU.
There are two ways to go about this:

#### UEFI/BIOS

Disable the Intel GPU in your UEFI/BIOS settings.  How to go about this differs per motherboard. For an Asrock Z77 Pro4 it meant setting:

```
Advanced > North Bridge Configuration > IGPU Multi-Monitor: Disabled
```

On other motherboards it can probably be found in a similar location.

#### Blacklist Kernel Driver

The other option is to blacklist the kernel driver (`i1915`), which is explained in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/110343/81657) answer.
Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add: `blacklist i915`.

This can be done by switching to a TTY (`ctrl`+`alt`+`f1`), logging in and running:

```
echo "blacklist i915" | sudo tee --append /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

After rebooting, the Intel GPU will no longer work but the Nvidia GPU will work and (hopefully) Xorg will no longer crash.

Comment: Blacklisting is not possible on Optimus chipsets

Answer (score 2):

First I switched to a console (CTRL-ALT-F1).
Then I removed all nvidia stuff with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nvidia-*
```

and reinstalled the nouveau driver using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-nouveu
```

then

```
sudo reboot
```

I know this is probably not what both of us want but it is still better than no desktop at all...

My Setup (for completeness):

- OS: Ubuntu 15.04
- CPU: Intel i5-4570S
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT 610

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. Unfortunately the Nouveau driver is very crash-happy for me. As I said in another comment, disabling the Intel GPU completely solved the issue for me.  I'll add an answer with some details about how to do this when I have some time to tinker.
I've upvoted your answer as it is a workaround that might be satisfactory for people googling this issue.

Comment: This did notw ork for me. The system still crashes. The reinstall command did not work because the package was not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `nvidia-xconfig` after nvidia drivers installation. Then reboot.