# Ubuntu freeze on logout

Tags: reboot, session

I've just installed Ubuntu 15.04 and I'm experiencing a trouble when I try to logout. I think this is a recurrent problem with Ubuntu since I already experienced this same problem with release 14.10 (the problem was gone by himself, I think...).
When I try to logout, the whole system freezes instantly. TTYs aren't available and the only thing that works is Alt+SysRq+b (emergency reboot)... This happens when:

- I try to reboot, via the UI or using `reboot`
- I try to close my session (no reboot)
- I use `kill -9 -1`

Also, the laptop doesn't enter the sleep mode when I close the lip.

On the Internet, I found a guy that replaces this line in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

by:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

This works, I can reboot the computer, but when rebooted, it have a lot of problems (keys repeated 25 times on a single keydown, wifi is down...).

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

**EDIT:**
I've noticed graphics-related errors in the dmesg logs:

```
[    7.577765] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] HUB_INIT timed out
[    7.577769] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 409000 - done 0x00000240
[    7.577774] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 409000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
[    7.577778] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 409000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000006 0x00000000
[    7.577780] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 502000 - done 0x00000340
[    7.577785] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 502000 - stat 0x80000000 0x00006500 0x00000000 0x00000000
[    7.577789] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 502000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000002 0x00000000
[    7.577791] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 50a000 - done 0x00000340
[    7.577796] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 50a000 - stat 0x80000000 0x00008e00 0x00000000 0x00000000
[    7.577801] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 50a000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000002 0x00000000
[    7.577803] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 512000 - done 0x00000300
[    7.577808] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 512000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00017f00 0x00000000 0x00000000
[    7.577812] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 512000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
[    7.577814] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    9.039096] wlan0: authenticate with e8:be:81:93:04:24
....
[   12.794968] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[   12.795090] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   12.795094] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[   27.813811] nouveau E[     DRM] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [DRM]
[   27.813874] sched: RT throttling activated
[   27.864541] pci_pm_runtime_suspend(): nouveau_pmops_runtime_suspend+0x0/0xf0 [nouveau] returns -16
```

But if I use the nvidia drivers, I get a black screen at boot and I need to purge the nvidia drivers from the recovery mode. The reboot works in recovery mode, using the root console. So the problem is probably graphic-related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar issue, and did not find a proper solution yet too.

For now, I have temporarily blacklisted nouveau module and now living with i915:)

See here about blacklisting:
[How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

Comment: Ahah, I've done the same thing one or two days after I posted this, and it worked too :)
Since it seems to be an acceptable fix, I accept your answer to help other people.