# nvidia-prime doesn't turn off Nvidia card while using intel graphics

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

So I'm using nvidia-352-updates and nvidia-prime. It also installed bbswitch and some other packages.
I've set nvidia-prime to use the Intel card. It is using that card but powertop reports that the nvidia card is still ON.

Then, I've tried setting off the nvidia card with `sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF` but the card remains ON.

Is there any way to turn it off? Or I'll have to blacklist the nvidia card?

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev a1)
```

Also, my card is a 620M but somehow lspci detects a 630M, will that cause any error? are those cards different?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Can you disable the card in your BIOS? (that's what I do!) **:-)**

Comment: No, I don't have such option :(

Comment: Blacklisting *or uninstalling* the driver is your only option then!  **:-(** Want me to convert this to an answer???

Comment: Okay. I just added bbswitch.conf to `/etc/modprobe.d` and write `options bbswitch load_state=0` so with that it remains off until I use it at least.

Comment: Cool!  Do you want to self-answer or me to answer?  **:-)**

Comment: Do as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance! favour returned!  You're an 8-rep user already!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable any hardware (nVidia or otherwise):

1. Remove the hardware from the machine if you'll never need it again. (this includes removing nVidia, WiFi, ... hardware from laptops)
2. If you only need the hardware infrequently: disable it in the BIOS (that's how I run with my nVidia card: enable it when needed)
3. If your set-up, doesn't allow you to disable/remove your hardware [blacklisting the kernel module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules) until your need it is your best choice.