# AMD A10 8700p overheats on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, amd-processor, tlp

I recently got a HP Envy 15 ah150na laptop with an AMD A10 8700p CPU and and R6 8700p integrated graphics card. The problem is that the CPU temperature after 10-15 minutes of usage goes up to around 60C and does not really go down at all. I'm not entirely sure if the CPU or the GPU is to blame. The GPU itself uses the amdgpu driver from the oibaf PPA.

I'm running kernel version 4.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

TLP with the default configuration is installed as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to mention that the temperature is much lower on Windows 10 which came pre-installed. Also forgot to mention that changing the stock thermal paste (terribly applied) helped to shave off 5-10 degrees but it was not really enough. Also for some reason indicator-cpufreq doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Start the Computer and boot into the bios only.  There should be a System Status/Health Status with a temperature reading.  Let the computer sit idle 15 minutes.  If the temperature remains constant after 15 minutes switch to the stock Radeon driver and repeat the process while in ubuntu

Comment: Could you please point me to an article or tutorial for how to revert to the radeon driver? Other than that isn't amdgpu the default driver in 16.04?

Comment: [Stock Radeon Driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).  If that works, and you're wanting better performance, switch to the [BinaryBlob/Closed Source Driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD). Windows uses the Binary Blob Driver. As a rule of thumb 3rd Party PPA's usually contain Overclocked or buggy drivers.

Comment: There is not any fglrx (amd proprietary driver) for Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't think that `amdgpu` is supported by your APU (it only supports the newest gpu until now). To be sure run the command `inxi -SMCGxx`, paste the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add a link to your question (describe it as System Info).

Comment: As far as I know the proprietary driver is not supported on 16.04 anymore. As of the first link it seems to not mention anything about 16.04, Carrizo series or how to actually force Ubuntu to use the radeon driver instead of the amdgpu. I'm sorry that I'm so incompetent. It is just the first time I'm dealing with AMD drivers.

Comment: This is the output of inxi -SMMCGxx
http://paste.ubuntu.com/17771469/

Comment: Hmm so it does use amdgpu afterall. Try to blacklist amdgpu temporarily as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules. To do so, press `e` at grub menu and add `amdgpu.blacklist=yes` in the end of the linux line (it usually ends with `quite splash`). Then run again the `inxi` command and see if the Graphics driver changed to radeon. If it did, test the laptop for a while and check the temperatures and see if there is any difference...

Comment: Before you blacklist your only gpu driver see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/+bug/1577074), and upgrade kernels

Comment: @eyoung100 he already has the latest kernel...

Comment: Strangely enough amdgpu.blacklist=yes doesn't seem to change anything. inxi still outputs that the driver in use is ati,amdgpu and that radeon is unloaded.

Comment: True, I just tested it on my pc with radeon, you need to add `modprobe.blacklist=amdgpu` instead.

Comment: modprobe.blacklist=amdgpu successfully blacklisted amdgpu but now fbdev is in use. It seems to have had slightly negative effect on temperature but the performance is terrible.

Comment: I don't know anything more, you need to experiment yourself. Try blacklisting in the same way both amdgpu and fbdev. Also open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and search for radeon (if it's blacklisted there then comment the line by adding #). Remember do this only for testing, amdgpu is considered to be superior to radeon so if you see difference in temperatures then better find a way to configure amdgpu or try again with kernel 4.7 when it's released .

Comment: Also take a look at this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules

Comment: Also, try to enable amdgpu powerplay by adding `amdgpu.powerplay=1` to grub the same way as before as shown here http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-PP-4.5-Steps&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Phoronix+%28Phoronix%29 (don't know if it works for kernel 4.6).