# using opensource radeon driver instead of amdgpu

Tags: 16.04, xorg, radeon, amd-graphics

I've HP-15 av125ax laptop which has AMD Carrizo A10 CPU and R7 m360 dGPU. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu is loading amdgpu driver which is causig a lot of instability (crash on sleep, over heating till thermal shutdown). How do I switch to opensource radeon drivers. Ive tried blacklisting amdgpu and create entry "10-radeon.conf" in "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/", but that's not working

Contents of "10-radeon.conf"

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "radeon"
    MatchDriver "radeon"
    Driver "radeon"
EndSection
```

output of "lspci -nn | grep VGA"

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo [1002:9874] (rev c5)
```

content of blacklist file

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist amdgpu
```

output of "lsmod | grep amdgpu"

```
amdgpu                987136  3
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                    94208  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 amdgpu
drm                   360448  57 ttm,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu
```

output of "lsmod | grep radeon" is empty.

Regards

Comment: Please post output of lspci -nn | grep VGA

Comment: Blacklisting `amdgpu` in the kernel should definitely work. Make sure you're doing it correctly- [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules). As for overheating, I advise you disable your R7 dedicated GPU as it provides only ~10% more performance than your integrated Carrizo GPU.

Comment: Hay, @RogerG added output in question description.

Comment: Hay @PatrickNegus, I followed the same thread to blacklist driver :) . added blacklist and output of lsmod in question description

Comment: How did you disabled AMDGPU and enabled Radeonsi? have you found any solution?

Comment: @daniel I reverted to 15.10