# Stuck in boot loop after amdgpu-pro on 17.04

Tags: login, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I was trying to get *lutris* with league of legends running and unturned, I needed the *amdgpu-pro* and I saw that people have it working on ubuntu 17.

I download the installer and it actually runs all the way through so I restart and boom login loop.

- `lightdm` is fine.
- permissions in `/tmp` are fine.
- .Xauthority and .ICEauthority have the user permissions read and write and are owned by my user.
- `sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup` didnt help, I have undone the changes.
- I tried using lxdm and it doesnt work either.
- Running startx gives me these [logs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25209465/).

I tried uninstalling the drivers from recovery mode using apt and it works but I still get logged out immediately and the text input box on login is slightly messed up (probably because I have some messed up drivers installed as default now).

I have no idea what the problem is and I would really like to get back to Ubuntu.

```
GPU: AMD RADEON R9 290X
```

EDIT: Im dual booting linux with windows if that makes any difference.

EDIT: This happens for all users, not just mine.

Comment: did you blacklist the default `radeon` driver?

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output, or recovery mode prompt, of `ls -al /home/your_username/.*thority`. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @Tooniis how would I do that?

Comment: @heynnema Alright I included the permissions of .Xauthority and .ICEauthority

Comment: @8o7wer https://askubuntu.com/a/110343/632192