# Switch Ubuntu/Xubuntu to Integrated Graphics (from AMD)

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, mac, amd-graphics

I have an old IMac Mid 2012 Model. This model was known to have some issues with the GPU. Apple did have a replacement program but that window is now closed. Specs of the machine are available here - https://support.apple.com/kb/sp667?locale=en_IN (I upped my Ram to 24GB)

I have installed Xubuntu and wanted to know if I could switch Xubuntu to Integrated Graphics thus making my system useable again.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The AMD graphics seem to be supported out of the box. The system works perfectly with the Command Line Interface which I assume is running using Integrated Graphics. The processor is the Intel Sandy bridge CPU

Comment: Maybe blacklisting the radeon module will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules

Answer (score 1):

The link showing the specifications you've provided in the question gives the information that your machine has a dedicated NVIDIA GPU. That's the reason why I will provide you with instructions how to deactivate an AMD *and* a NVIDIA GPU in order to make only use of the integrated GPU.

**1. variant - In case your PC has a NVIDIA GPU (as provided in the specification link)**

Open a terminal and execute the following command : `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the line : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
So that it reads : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close the file and confirm the change by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then execute this command : `sudo update-grub` (to update the GRUB configuration)

**2. variant - In case your PC has an AMD GPU (as provided in the title of the question)**

Open a terminal and execute the following command : `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Add `radeon.modeset=0` to the line : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
So that it reads : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close the file and confirm the change by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then execute this command : `sudo update-grub` (to update the GRUB configuration)

Restart the PC, now you are using the integrated GPU only, the dedicated GPU is disabled.

Comment: This has not worked. I've tried this (option 2) already. My grub file details are available here - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69ef51b275ffa26401e41ada89f12077. My lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 reading is available here - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ff35c67078b1e543dacab4e35eed9be7

Comment: @letterhead Why did you disable the i915 intel drivers ? Please remove `i915.modeset=0` from the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line and remove `amdgpu.runpm=0` as well, because your lscpi output says Kernel modules: radeon. Also remove `nomodeset` from the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line, this parameter disables a lot of things and might be one of the reasons for your problem. It should only be used for troubleshooting in worst cases scenarios. Then reboot the system, I hope we see improvements.:)

Comment: System doesn't boot now. Can't get past the dev/sda2: clean, 330612/61022208 files... page. I assume I have broken something :(

Comment: @letterhead I suggest that you check what works and what not by booting from the (X)ubuntu installation Live media. Select "Try Ubuntu without installing" and boot without any parameter modification. When the Live desktop works, fine ... if not, boot with the parameter modification being provided in the answer. (Select "Try Ubuntu without installing", press the E key and add the parameter at the end of the linux line, then press F10 to boot) ... please report back the results. :)