# Permanently Disable Wireless Drivers and Wireless Internet on tablet-PC

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

running ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64

I need to completely disable wireless on my old windows tablet-PC (now running Ubuntu) preventing it from ever accessing networks wirelessly or the internet **ever again**, particularly after reboots. this is for security concern.

Normally you could disable the network card in the bios in a laptop or desktop motherboard, but on this tablet-PC it doesn't give me such option :<
Anyone know how I could achieve this on Ubuntu, i assume for example by deleting all wireless drivers?. thx

Answer (score 0):

The output of your systems dmesg might be useful in identifying your wireless controller.

You can blacklist the wireless module.  Depending on your wireless card manufacturer you would blacklist a different kernel module.

For instance, on my system with a Broadcom wireless controller I would blacklist b43.

> lsmod | grep b43
>   b43                   401408  0
>   bcma                   49152  1 b43
>   mac80211              659456  1 b43
>   cfg80211              499712  2 b43,mac80211
>   ssb                    57344  1 b43

Atheros controllers might be ath9k or ath10k_pci.

> lsmod | grep ath9k

This is a generic explanation of blacklisting.  Note the EDIT for the blacklist file name changed to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:
[How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

This is an example where someone asked the same question:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1622582