# Identify module name to blacklist

Tags: drivers, grub2, kernel, blacklist

Everybody knows that any kernel module can be blacklisted via GRUB line:

```
$ module_name.blacklist=yes
```

However, not everybody knows the exact name of module to blacklist. And that **is** the real problem! How to identify it?

For example, during of loading of GRUB I see:

```
rtlwifi firmware not available
```

which is quite useless of identification. Neither

```
rtlwifi.blacklist=yes
```

nor any other variants worked. How do I figure out the name?

The same thing goes with Bluetooth adapter. It throws:

```
 [ 9.366503] Bluethooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
```

Of course, `rtl_bt/rt18821a_fw.blacklist=yes` didn't work.

```
$ lsmod | grep rtl 
rtl8821ae             233472  0
btcoexist             131072  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8821ae
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  5 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8821ae
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
cfg80211              622592  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** What concerns *rtlwifi error* `lspci -v` listed only following

```
Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-87-2b-01
Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [158] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

And name `rtl8821ae` **already** was in my blacklist without any result, so it seems to be no-go.

What concerns *Bluethooth: hci0 error*, `lspci` [listed](https://pastebin.com/SSQNHiXZ) no Bluetooth modules or nothing similar to `rtl_bt`, maybe because Bluetooth adapter is not a PCI device.

Comment: What does `lsmod | grep rtl` tell us?

Comment: Added output to question

Comment: Something is clearly wrong with the blacklisting as rtl8821ae is still being loaded according to your `lsmod` above (but not used, as it says "0"). It's not clear what the actual problem is though, why you want to blacklist. Is it blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d` ? Try that, reboot, check it's not in lsmod. Are you using bluetooth?

Comment: No, I am not using bluetooth. I am trying to boot ubuntu-based Clonezilla image and exclude unnecessary modules. As I know it, it supports blacklisting only via `grub.cfg`but I will try `/etc/modprobe.d`

Comment: what device are you trying to blacklist?

Comment: rtl8821ae and rtlwifi. I suppose these are bluetooth and wifi modules. I know only the errors I see during the boot, which I given in the question body

Comment: "ubuntu-based Clonezilla image" the Clonezilla is just a copy of a disk AFAIU, so which version of Ubu is it? Did you try blacklisting in /etc/modprobe.d/?

Comment: `so which version of Ubu is it` 18.10, Artful Aadvark

Comment: I tried `modprobe.blacklist=rtl8821ae` directive of CLonezilla and it seems to work, but only for `rtlwifi`. `Bluethooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin` error is thrown anyway. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can boot without blacklisting the driver and then use `lspci -v` to display the information about the hardware and the kernel driver and module associated with it. The `Kernel Modules:` section should show module name you need to blacklist (most likely)

Sample output:

```
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc Qemu virtual machine
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 9
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4
```

Module name in above example is `i2c_piix4`

Let me know if that works. Source of this info is https://askubuntu.com/a/110343/142100

Comment: Tried your suggestion without any result. See the details in my update.

Comment: Does rmmod rtl8821ae do anything after you have already booted.