# Remove NSA encryption Speck

Tags: encryption

The file `speck.ko` can be found in `/lib/modules/4.18.1-041801-generic/kernel/crypto` and [it was built by the NSA](https://www.itnews.com.au/news/new-linux-kernel-debuts-adds-more-suspect-nsa-sourced-crypto-500094) (added since Linux Kernel 4.17).

I really want to remove this thing from my computer. If I see it in the `/crypto` folder, does it mean it is enabled by default and used somehow?

Comment: Blacklist that module to remove it, let find that article

Comment: I don't know how any privacy conscious open-source dev can think that NSA, world's biggest anti-encryption spy agency lets people use an encryption developed by them without any backdoor. It's sad that they succeeded including it in Linux, world's most famous open-source project used heavily by privacy advocates.

Comment: @HattinGokbori87 it baffles ones imagination how adding that module will help us, but I guess money has powers :-(!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Via the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file

   - Create that file (if it does not exist) and add the following line into it:

     ```
     blacklist CONFIG_CRYPTO_SPECK
     ```
   - **Note:** They might make it dependent on another module hence it will load regardless, so the workaround is to add the line in this way rather than how it is written above:

     ```
     install CONFIG_CRYPTO_SPECK /bin/false
     ```

     - This force the module to always fail loading and will effectively blacklist that module and any other that depends on it **SO TAKE NOTE**.
   - Then reboot.
2. Via command line:

   - Simply add this to your bootloader's kernel line

     ```
     module_blacklist=modname1,modname2,modname3
     # or
     modprobe.blacklist=MODULE_NAME
     ```

     - **NOTE:** When you are blacklisting more than one module, note that they are separated by commas only. Spaces or anything else might presumably break the syntax.
   - Then boot as normal and the module should not be loaded.
3. TIP:- From `man modprobe` I see the `-b` option which you can use after finding the name via `lsmod`:

   ```
   sudo lsmod
   sudo modprobe -b <name_of_module>
   ```

Sources:

https://itsfoss.com/nsas-encryption-algorithm-in-linux-kernel-is-creating-unease-in-the-community/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=nsas_controversial_algorithm_video_player_and_other_linux_stuff&utm_term=2018-08-20

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Blacklisting

Comment: Do I have to replace `modname1`, `modname2`, `modname3`? And what do I write instead of it? `CONFIG_CRYPTO_SPECK` or `speck.ko`

Comment: run `sudo lsmod` to get the name and substitute accordingly