# Ubuntu 18.04 not shutdown

Tags: shutdown

MSI GF63 8Rd

ubuntu not shutdown

I tried several options on the command line and nothing

I tried to change the grub to: add modprobe.blacklist = nouveau after quiet splash and nothing

Help

I have an msi gf63 8rd, i7-8750H Hexa Core, Chipset: Intel, HM370 Graphics Card: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 + NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB GDDR5 Max-Q, I install UBUNTU or MINT and the pc does not power off.
I installed ENDLESS OS and it works fine.
The grub in both the ENDLESS OS, UBUNTU, and MINT is the same.
The kernel in ENDLESS is 4.18.0.11 I updated the kernel in MINT to 4.18 and it still does not hang

dmesg errors:

```
[    0.000000] ACPI: Core revision 20170831
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload-210)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_cfhd4) while loading table (20170831/tbxfload-228)
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 7 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)

.
.

[    0.065542] ACPI: \: Used as boot ECDT EC to handle transactions
[    0.070711] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.070722] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [PXSX]
[    0.070723] No Arguments are initialized for method [PXSX]
[    0.070725] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.070730] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP04.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    0.072545] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.072553] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [PXSX]
[    0.072554] No Arguments are initialized for method [PXSX]
[    0.072556] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.072560] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP08.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    0.074393] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP13.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.074400] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [PXSX]
[    0.074402] No Arguments are initialized for method [PXSX]
[    0.074403] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.074407] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP12.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
.
.

[    8.254890] dpc 0000:00:1d.0:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    8.254911] dpc 0000:00:1d.4:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    8.254966] efifb: probing for efifb
.
.

[   10.334776] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   10.334830] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
.
.

[   17.758015] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (378) occurred get tpm pcr allocation

.
.
[   18.218944] cannonlake-pinctrl INT3450:00: pin 16 cannot be used as IRQ
[   18.218947] genirq: Setting trigger mode 8 for irq 137 failed (intel_gpio_irq_type+0x0/0x140)
[   18.218978] i2c_hid i2c-CUST0001:00: i2c-CUST0001:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[   18.219815] cannonlake-pinctrl INT3450:00: pin 16 cannot be used as IRQ
[   18.219817] genirq: Setting trigger mode 8 for irq 137 failed (intel_gpio_irq_type+0x0/0x140)
[   18.219824] i2c_hid i2c-CUST0001:00: Could not register for CUST0001:00 interrupt, irq = 137, ret = -1
[   18.219845] i2c_hid: probe of i2c-CUST0001:00 failed with error -1
[   18.220428] intel-lpss 0000:00:1e.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)

.
.

[   22.942323] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: secboot: VPR scrubber binary failed!
[   22.942334] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -22
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Not beeing able to shut down is often an acpi or a graphics card problem. Since you blacklisted nouveau I assume you have a Nvidia GC. 
The devices are to be blacklisted in

```
/etc/modprobe.d/somefile.conf
```

"somefile.conf" can be any given name. More information about blacklisting is here :[How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)
Using

```
lsmod
```

will show you the loaded kernel modules that you might try to blacklist.

```
dmesg
```

might tell you why the poweroff does not work.

Comment: I have an msi gf63 8rd, i7-8750H Hexa Core, Chipset: Intel, HM370 Graphics Card: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 + NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB GDDR5 Max-Q, I install UBUNTU or MINT and the pc does not power off.
I installed ENDLESS OS and it works fine.
The grub in both the ENDLESS OS, UBUNTU, and MINT is the same.
The kernel in ENDLESS is 4.18.0.11 I updated the kernel in MINT to 4.18 and it still does not hang

Comment: I have several errors when I run dmesg

Comment: Solved with nvidia driver installation
Thank you