# How do i turn off the trackpoint within wayland?

Tags: mouse, wayland, xinput, libinput, trackpoint

My laptop has a wonky trackpoint that keeps on moving the mouse around.

When using xorg, i can use this command to shut it off:
xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0

seems like xinput is not a thing on wayland? A quick search gave me libinput, but libinput gives me no possibility to shut down the trackpoint (as far as i can see)

So how would I turn off the trackpoint in wayland?
Or is there maybe another way of doing this than xinput/libinput?

System info:

Toshiba Portege Z30A

Ubuntu 19.10 GNOME

*Update:

I found this discussion: https://gist.github.com/fghaas/3406be59095de212182f1803a503a64b#file-75-input-rules

Which seems to do exactly what I need, but I don't understand how to execute it. Could I get some help making sense of it? Where do I put what?

Comment: Right, `xinput` is a X11-only tool. I can't offhand write an answer, but a few possibilities that come to my mind: α) Did you look at Gnome settings for "Mouse and Touchpad"? There's an option to disable touchpad, I assume there should one for trackpoint too. β) Some options unfortunately have no an UI for them. So if α didn't work, you can find out which gsetting gets changed when UI disables touchpad, and try using `dconf-editor` to find an analogous setting for the trackpoint γ) if nothing helped, libinput has "quirks" subsystem, which can be used to ignore the device too.

Comment: δ) You can also blacklist the trackpoint driver.

Comment: There is no option to disable it in the settings.

Comment: If you can direct me to something about these 'quirks'? or how to blacklist the driver, that would be helpful.

Comment: I found this: https://gist.github.com/fghaas/3406be59095de212182f1803a503a64b#file-75-input-rules

Which seems to be exactly what I look for, but I don't understand how to go about executing it. Maybe someone could help me ?

Comment: No, what you linked is an udev rule, not libinput. Tbh, I don't know what is possible with udev regarding a trackpoint, maybe you could disable it. Anyway, [here's an example of a libinput quirk usage](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/316#note_182509). Judging [by documentation for `AttrEventCodeDisable`](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-quirks.html#list-of-supported-device-quirks), you can pass it a trackpoint movement event. Its name, in turn, you can get by executing `evemu-record` command, and trying to use the trackpoint.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you asked about how to blacklist a driver too. You can see examples [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/110343/266507)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me today:

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/99-myfavoritetrackpoint.rules
```

In that file:

```
# ALPS DualPoint Stick: Ignore as input device
ATTRS{name}=="*DualPoint Stick", ENV{ID_INPUT}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_MOUSE}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_POINTINGSTICK}=""
```

If that's not your device name, you would probably do the following and look for your device name to replace in the above command:

```
sudo apt-get install libinput-tools
sudo libinput list-devices
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a billion!

Comment: Works for ThinkPads too -
`# ALPS ThinkPad TrackPoint: Ignore as input device
ATTRS{name}=="*TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint", ENV{ID_INPUT}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_MOUSE}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_POINTINGSTICK}=""`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my HP Elitebook 8470p too:

```
sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/99-myfavoritetrackpoint.rules
```

then in the file:

````
ATTRS{name}=="PS/2 Generic Mouse", ENV{ID_INPUT}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_MOUSE}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_POINTINGSTICK}=""```

use: `sudo apt-get install libinput-tools;
sudo libinput list-devices` to get the name of your pointing stick
````

Answer (score 0):

On recent Thinkpads ~2023 above solution didn't work for me. However with guidance from following [post](https://cubiclenate.com/2024/02/27/disable-input-devices-in-wayland/) I could make it easily.

First find folder location of our device:

`grep -a2 TrackPoint  /proc/bus/input/devices`

Then append 1 to the inhibited button and include folder `/sys/` before the location of the output of the `S:` section, example:
`S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5`

As root:

`echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/inhibited`