# How to remove the GobiNet and GobiSerial driver from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers

How to remove the GobiNet and GobiSerial driver from Ubuntu 16.04?
or in general how can I remove any driver from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Removing drivers

To remove drivers from memory use:

```
modprobe -vr GobiSerial
modprobe -vr GobiNet
```

To prevent drivers from loading in the first place see blacklisting:

- [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

### Gobiserial specific

If your desire is to fix bad drivers then as per this [website](https://www.orbit-lab.org/wiki/Software/hDrivers) you must install firmware updates via Windows, not Linux:

> #### FIRMWARE UPDATE: (Incase you need one)
>
> The firmware update has to be done on windows. Insert the device into a windows box, and let it
> install drivers and enumerate interafaces. Make sure you can see the
> managment webpage.

Note the three typos in the original instructions, it's a bad omen....

Comment: @https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix i want to completely remove the driver from my system?

Comment: @srg Use `dkms status` to show what drivers are recompiled on kernel update. Do they show up in the list?

Comment: dkms status  is showing nothing.

Comment: @srg That means `dkms` won't automatically recompile the drivers with the next kernel upgrade and hopefully they will disappear on their own if you don't manually recompile them. You can use `locate GobiSerial` and `locate GobiNet` to get the physical locations of the drivers.

Comment: i have upgraded the kernel but drivers are not removed?

Comment: What do the `locate` commands return?

Comment: It shows the paths where GobiSerial n GobiNet files are present

Comment: @srg moving them from those paths to your home directory would be like deleting them. If system works ok after rebooting, then deleting them will be OK. If system doesn't work then move them back. I could not find any official instructions for uninstalling them from developer.