# Merlin U740 USB 2.0 camera not working

Tags: drivers, 18.04, usb

I have a USB camera: Novatel Wireless Merlin U740 (https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:1410-1410) and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (Ubuntu 18.04, everything up to date).

Here is what I get from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1410:1410 Novatel Wireless Merlin U740 (non-Vodafone)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1ea7:0064  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg` after plugging it in:

```
[  667.771452] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  668.012445] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1410, idProduct=1410, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  668.012447] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  668.012449] usb 3-2: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[  668.012450] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[  668.021479] option 3-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  668.023851] option 3-2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  668.025476] option 3-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  668.025536] option 3-2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
```

`lsmod | grep video`

```
uvcvideo               94208  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              208896  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

`ls /dev/video*`

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

I switched to proprietary Nvidia drivers but that didn't help (rebooted afterwards). Given that I'm out of ideas, did anyone had similar issues with this particular cam or one from that manufacturer?

It's probably worth pointing out that the same cam works on my laptop with the same distro and kernel installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu thinks it is the modem. Try to [blacklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules) `option` driver. The `uvcvideo` should be loaded automatically in this case on the next boot.

Answer (score 4):

Just a follow up to linuxbuild's answer...

For this particular camera, which I also own, on LinuxMint 18.3, I added the following to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf, and it worked after reboot:

```
blacklist usb_wwan
install usb_wwan /bin/false
```

Likely the last line is the only one needed, but I was working my way down the "how to blacklist drivers" thread, and that is when it worked.

Comment: For the record this answer worked for me in a Raspberry PI 4 with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). Thank you @Sir_Ty

Comment: @Sir_Ty you made my day man!!

Comment: Still works for ubuntu 22.04. Also confirming that it is just enough to add  `install usb_wwan /bin/false`
Note that the camera will still show with the wrong name: `Novatel Wireless Merlin U740 (non-Vodafone)` if you run `lsusb` after applying the fix