# External webcam device not found by some programs after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, usb, 20.04, webcam, devices

Purely as the result of the upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to 20.04LTS, my external webcam is not found by some software any longer.

#### Situation

1. `uname -r` says `5.4.0-54-generic` (so this answer [should not apply](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245498/446253))
2. `lsusb` says: ` Bus 006 Device 007: ID 046d:08d9 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam IM/Connect
3. `dmesg` says

   ```
   [ 2440.365843] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using uhci_hcd  
   [ 2440.577885] usb 6-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=08d9, bcdDevice= 1.00
   [ 2440.577888] usb 6-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
   [ 2440.580922] gspca_main: gspca_zc3xx-2.14.0 probing 046d:08d9
   [ 2441.795952] input: gspca_zc3xx as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/input/input21
   ```
4. `lsmod` says

   ```
   ... 
   videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 gspca_main
   videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
   videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 gspca_main
   videobuf2_common       49152  2 gspca_main,videobuf2_v4l2
   videodev              225280  4 
   gspca_main,gspca_zc3xx,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common  
   ...
   ```
5. `file /dev/video0` says `/dev/video0: character special (81/0)`
6. Cheese 3.34.0 responds from the start with

   [image: screenshot cheese]

   and Skype even more plainly with

   [image: screenshot skype]

However, the web-conferencing system [Big Blue Button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigBlueButton) does work (via Firefox 83.0).

The similar questions suggested seem date back to 2012-2014 and are not current any longer.
I found [this one closer to my case](https://askubuntu.com/q/1212050/446253) and used it as a blueprint to collect info, but its solution does not apply here.

Any tip for restoring full functionalities much appreciated.

Comment: Just found that the problem fixed for 5.4.0.33 returned with kernel 5.4.0.52 just two patches before mine: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1881757/comments/5

Comment: Still broken on 5.4.0-65