# How to unload a kernel module which is in use and has a recursive module dependency?

Tags: drivers, kernel, serial-port, modprobe

I habe a driver for my ELM 327 an it uses the pl2303 module which depends on the usbserial and this again depends on the pl2303 module.

What I tried:

```
sudo modprobe -r usbserial pl2303
sudo modprobe -r pl2303 usbserial
sudo modprobe -rf usbserial
sudo modprobe -rf pl2303
sudo rmmod --force pl2303
sudo rmmod --force usbserial
```

result of rmmod:

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:799 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'usbserial': Resource temporarily unavailable
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module usbserial: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

result of modprobe:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbserial is in use.
```

Also I tried it with the drivers loaded and unloaded.

[image: kernel modules reference each other[1]]

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Some additional reading on `pl2303`: [EP-44 serial printer via USB adapter: Linux](https://darrengoossens.wordpress.com/tag/pl2303/)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to blacklist kernel modules.

Checkout this post about [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

Comment: Although you answered your own question, I'm upvoting to help you recover lost bounty points.

Answer (score 0):

When you look into dmesg do you see a line where the device was detected when it was plugged in? Ubuntu should have FTDI support out of the box. Normally you would just access it by typing screen /dev/ttyUSB# 38400.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I don't want to connect to like that. I just need to unload it from the kernel.

Comment: You could try blacklisting it by editing /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist and adding blacklist driver-name. Maybe that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As OP mentioned rather than unloading module it is easier to not load it in the first place. This is accomplished by blacklisting the module:

- [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

To summarize answers in link:

Just open your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file and add drivername using following syntax:

```
blacklist pl2303
```

Save the file and Reboot. The offending module will no longer be loaded at startup.