# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, nftables

I have migrated my Ubuntu Focal server firewall backend from legacy iptables to netfilter, by running `update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-nft` and rebooting the server. Now all tables shown in `iptables-legacy -S` are empty, but when I run `iptables -S` the last line always says:

```
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

I have since removed `iptables-legacy` from alternatives using the following command:

```
update-alternatives --remove iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

And now only the netfilter version is shown

```
root@iBug-Server:~# update-alternatives --display iptables
iptables - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
  link currently points to /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
  link iptables is /usr/sbin/iptables
  slave iptables-restore is /usr/sbin/iptables-restore
  slave iptables-save is /usr/sbin/iptables-save
/usr/sbin/iptables-nft - priority 20
  slave iptables-restore: /usr/sbin/iptables-nft-restore
  slave iptables-save: /usr/sbin/iptables-nft-save
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Please edit your question adding the output for `sudo update-alternatives --display iptables`.

Comment: @DougSmythies Done.

Comment: As I understaqnd the warning, it says that you have to run `iptables-legacy` command to see what rules are in legacy format. Then you can convert them to netfilter format.

Comment: @SorenA My legacy table are all empty, with no rules, no custom chains, and all default chains having policy `ACCEPT`

Comment: Well, my `--display` output is pretty much the same (I seem to have a `priority 10` area, related to `iptables-legacy`, which I guess you removed). I run a very complicated iptables rule set and have not seen your warning. Note: my iptables rule set is loaded via bash script, I don't use iptables-persistent or iptables-save. I have another server, but it is still set to legacy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error messages says, it's because the legacy (non-netfilter) iptables subsystem is present. The most common cause is that the `iptables-legacy` command is called, which loads the legacy modules.

There are 5 modules related to legacy iptables, one for each table. (**Note**: The module names begin with `iptable_`, no S here)

```
iptable_filter
iptable_nat
iptable_mangle
iptable_raw
iptable_security
```

When ANY of them is loaded, `iptables-nft` decides that the legacy iptables is present, and emits the said warning.

Similarly, there are 5 more modules for legacy IPv6 iptables, each beginning with `ip6table_` (no S here, too).

After migrating to netfilter, those 10 modules can be safely removed with `rmmod` and blacklisted.

**Note again** that using `blacklist iptable_filter` doesn't work here because this directive only prevents automatic loading, but not manual loading via `modprobe(8)` or another command. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/853903/612877) using `install <modulename> /bin/false` should correctly prevent the module from loading under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, as it is written in `man rmmod`, we can remove the modules by `modprobe -r iptable_filter iptable_nat iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security`, thus we do not need to blacklist them.

Comment: @pa4080 Blacklisting these modules prevent them from being accidentally loaded again. For example, when you run `iptables-legacy` with any valid argument, it loads the modules and brings back the issue you're trying to solve. This may happen unexpectedly with certain software that hard-coded `iptables-legacy` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I got this warning after selecting the `docker` package when running the Ubuntu 22.04 installer. (I did not get this when I skipped selecting packages and installed Docker manually.)

> After migrating to netfilter, those 10 modules can be safely removed with rmmod and blacklisted.

If any rule causes one of the 10 modules to be used, when you attempt to remove the module you will get an error such as

```
# modprobe -r iptable_nat
modprobe: FATAL: Module iptable_nat is in use.
```

To completely get rid of `# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present`, I needed to wipe out completely `iptables`, `ip6tables`, `iptables-legacy` and `ip6tables-legacy`. **Examine all four and check if anything from the pair of `legacy`s needs to be incorporated into the respective non-`legacy` pair.** Below, I am using the saved non-`legacy`s files after determining that I did not need to incorporate any deltas from the `legacy`s.

```sh
iptables-save > iptables-save.txt
ip6tables-save > ip6tables-save.txt
iptables-legacy-save > iptables-legacy-save.txt
ip6tables-legacy-save > ip6tables-legacy-save.txt

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -F
iptables -X

ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -t nat -F
ip6tables -t nat -X
ip6tables -t mangle -F
ip6tables -t mangle -X
ip6tables -F
ip6tables -X

iptables-legacy -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables-legacy -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables-legacy -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables-legacy -t nat -F
iptables-legacy -t nat -X
iptables-legacy -t mangle -F
iptables-legacy -t mangle -X
iptables-legacy -F
iptables-legacy -X

ip6tables-legacy -P INPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables-legacy -P FORWARD ACCEPT
ip6tables-legacy -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables-legacy -t nat -F
ip6tables-legacy -t nat -X
ip6tables-legacy -t mangle -F
ip6tables-legacy -t mangle -X
ip6tables-legacy -F
ip6tables-legacy -X

for x in _raw _mangle _security _nat _filter; do
    modprobe -r "iptable${x}"
    modprobe -r "ip6table${x}"
done

iptables-restore < iptables-save.txt
ip6tables-restore < ip6tables-save.txt
```

You will also want to run

```sh
update-alternatives --remove iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

Please consult other resources about `update-alternatives`, migrating from iptables to nft, and the security ramifications of completely clearing iptables when the machine is connected to the network. If you have Docker installed, you will not be able to `apt-get purge iptables` because it is a dependency of `docker-ce`.