# How to temporarily blacklist nvidia driver at boot time

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kernel, blacklist

I would like to disable the Nvidia driver at boot time in Grub, on specific grub entries.

I noticed that adding `module.blacklist=nvidia` was the way to go. ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/831297/917540))

I rebooted my system, edited the GRUB command line with `e`, and at the end of the `linux`, I appended:

```
... module.blacklist=nvidia
```

However, the nvidia driver is still loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1007616  0
nvidia_drm             49152  10
nvidia_modeset       1183744  14 nvidia_drm
nvidia              19722240  616 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   491520  14 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
```

➡️ Am I using the wrong syntax ?

➡️ Is there something I am missing during the boot ?

In the meantime, I'm switching the driver using the `additional driver` tool before I reboot:

[additional_driver_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEVdA.png)

Running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If you disable `nvidia` module, the system won't boot. The `nouveau` driver is blacklisted when you install proprietary drivers. It is a bad idea.

Comment: But how do i install them both, and blacklist one when I need the other ?
And why my system was able to boot, even though I blacklisted the only GPU driver ?

Comment: It is a complex task and can't be done quite easily. You could boot probably because some dependent modules still pulled `nvidia`.

Comment: You can turn off nvidia for next boot with `sudo prime-select intel` then turn it on again for following boot with `sudo prime-select nvidia`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is

```
module_blacklist=nvidia .
```

Note the underscore instead of the dot.

Comment: Thanks !
I guess my source was wrong then.