# Ubuntu 20.04 rtl8822ce Wifi stops routing after about 3 seconds

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, realtek-wireless

A weird problem I have tried resolving all day and now I need ideas.
A new laptop HP *) with rtl8822ce wifi with correct drivers I believe **). Ubuntu is 20.04 with 16.04->18.04->20.04 history.

When I connect to our home wifi, I can ping about 3 seconds our router or google (10.0.0.1/8.8.8.8) after which all I get is "Destination Host Unreachable" until I disconnect and connect again. Every time I reconnect, 3 seconds of connectivity only.
The home wifi is made with 3 Tenda Novas as a Mesh network.
All other systems can connect this network all the time including 3 Ubuntus, 3 Apples, 3 Androids, one LG TV, a Windows and many more. No problems with internet access at any time.
The rtl8822ce connects to AP with 2,4GHz or 5GHz, behaviour is the same - 3 secs of connectivity only.

Second I test same with my phone's mobile access point. The rtl8822ce/Ubuntu 20.04 have no problems connecting this AP and staying connected to it.

Same behaviour with fresh Ubuntu 20.04 live usb stick (to overrule the upgrade history). Mesh home wifi 3 secs online, ad hoc phone AP stay connected all along.

I Am completely clueless after spending a day troubleshooting driver issues. I believe the driver is installed okay ***) but something else is now stopping my packets flow to router/internet.

But what?

BR, Timo

*)

```
    siiri@siiri-hp:~$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: siiri-hp Kernel: 5.4.0-80-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
           Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Laptop 15s-eq1xxx v: N/A 
           serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: HP model: 8707 v: 37.19 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: AMI 
           v: F.41 date: 04/13/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 42.5 Wh condition: 42.5/42.5 Wh (100%) 
           model: Hewlett-Packard Primary status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 
           type: MCP arch: Zen rev: 1 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
           bogomips: 28446 
           Speed: 1603 MHz min/max: 1400/2375 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1656 2: 1291 
           3: 1212 4: 1397 5: 1397 6: 1397 
Graphics:  Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A bus ID: 03:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: ati,fbdev 
           unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6 
           direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: AMD vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 03:00.1 
           Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor 
           vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.5 
           Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.6 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-80-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
           vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtw_pci v: N/A port: f000 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 90:0f:0c:3d:09:9f 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 106.36 GiB (44.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: BC511 HFM256GDJTNI-82A0A 
           size: 238.47 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 233.17 GiB used: 106.35 GiB (45.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 977.0 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 53.8 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 311 Uptime: 21m Memory: 7.21 GiB used: 1.81 GiB (25.1%) 
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
           inxi: 3.0.38
```

**)

```
    siiri@siiri-hp:~$ lsmod | grep rtw
rtwpci                 24576  0
rtw88                 618496  1 rtwpci
mac80211              847872  2 rtwpci,rtw88
cfg80211              704512  2 mac80211,rtw88
```

***)

```
siiri@siiri-hp:~$ iwconfig wlo1
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Karhu"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: 58:D9:D5:E3:B0:5C   
          Bit Rate=526.6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Well. Father (me) spent approximately 8hrs solving above problem. When I told the daughter you cannot get the new laptop just quite yet, she said why don't you reboot the main AP (1st Tenda Nova)?
This helped the connection to stay up for minutes after which it died in similar way as earlier. Some buffer gets filled somewhere? Why only with this wifi card?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

(comment field too small)

Yes waltinator, I kept reading dmesg & journalctl both to no avail for hours. Plot thickened yesterday evening when I forced the router dhcp to give that poor HP/Ubuntu/rtl8822ce a new address. Connection stayed up for tens of minutes and I though it's sorted now.

This morning revealed the bad status. Power up HP, nice 4ms ping and after opening Firefox to come here to update this thread with victory comments - no internet.

I started reading forums again and this time they guided me to https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 (many broken links yesterday to same gentleman's rtw88_new).

I compiled the driver as per instructions, blacklisted ([How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)) rtwpci and rtw88 and rebooted. Now I have rtw_8822ce, rtw_8822c, rtw_pci and rtw_core and ping is flowing.

Unfortunately the behavior is still the same: 28% packet loss and they come periodically, say, 30secs of nice routing then 5secs of no replies and same sequence again and again.
While ping answers get lost in transit, dmesg and journalctl output absolutely no entries or errors.
When the route is clear, Speedtest.net gives 96mbps down/10,5Mbps up for this 100Mbps broadband so it's not about stalling network either.

This may very well be due to my local network as the behavior changed so much when I told router to give another address to the HP/Ubuntu/rtl8822ce.

My network is cable broadband, Tp-link TL-R605 v1.0 router, 3 x Tenda Nova Mesh3 wifi APs. No other client has problems in that network.
I will never again buy cheapo Chinaware again (Tenda) albeit cannot say it's their fault.

I guess my next test step need to be to clone back the factory Win image and try with that? Perhaps I try U20.10 before that..

Comment: No, U20.10 didn't change the situation at all :(

Comment: Mysterious are the packets ways. Suspecting my home network I decided to shut down all slave cells and main Nova and the router and the HP itself. Now I have a working network on the HP too for over an hour!

I'm afraid I will be here again but now I hand HP over to daughter and ask her to report outages ;)

For anyone who may stumble upon this finding the HP model here, I suggest Ubuntu 20.10 or newer as screen dimming, suspend & other special keys started to work right after the upgrade.

Comment: Hi. I came back to confirm that daughter said the PC has been OK all these days. I did see some packet drops on 23rd July when I finally gave the lappy to her. Perhaps they just does not show up on normal internet use. All good ;)

Comment: Last update, I hope. I believe the whole mess was because of Tp-link TL-R605's ARP spoofing detection which was enabled by default, and DHCPs address reservation with "mac-ip binding"-button and an ignorant administrator pressing it when assigning permanent IPs for some home devices.
Don't press those buttons if you don't exactly know what they do. Doh..