# How to force Intel Graphics instead of Radeon?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, switchable-graphics

I am struggling to find how to change graphics renderer in ubuntu. My radeon card gives off all kinds of corruptions so I want to change my graphics adapter to Intel Graphics

Here are some outputs:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5730 / 6570M]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Mobility Radeon HD 5730
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

and

```
$ glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD REDWOOD (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.11.0-16-generic, LLVM 11.0.1)
```

I tried:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"
```

But I don't think this changed anything.

Comment: It is a laptop because, as you can see, it uses mobility radeon graphics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules)

Answer (score 1):

Editing /etc/default/grub so the line looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"
```

worked for me.