# How to disable the loading a kernel module (firmware) when the system boots?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, iwlwifi

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my laptop (lenovo V330-15IKB).
How can I force the system to avoid loading a kernel module during startup (boot)?
And how can I enable the module again?

In my case I want to avoid loading the wifi firmware iwlwifi.

lspci -nnk

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth [8086:3166] (rev 99)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth [8086:4210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I have some problems when booting and loging into the system (system is slow and laggy). I wan to temporary disable the iwlwifi module/firmware/driver to check if it is the cause (root) of the problem.

Comment: just be aware that if you disable iwlwifi you will have no wifi connection

Comment: @Esther I am aware of that. To avoid loading them I follow this the answers on this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules.