# Ubuntu can not start after crash

Tags: asus

I installed version 23.04 and everything was working OK. Suddenly, with the session blocked, I try to enter the key in gnome and the system does not respond (the graphical interface, if I changed the TTY I could operate the terminal). After disconnecting the wifi, the equipment is completely hung, so I turn it off by button.

When starting ubuntu again, it does not finish loading the processes and it hangs with the following message:

[image]

If I change TTY I can open a terminal and see disk info etc. but it doesn't start ubuntu or GNOME correctly.

Do you have any idea what it could be?

Thank you

Nicolás

Comment: Have you tried to blacklist the module by adding `modprobe.blacklist=cs35l41-hda` to the kernel commandline?

Comment: Looks like a known problem with kernel 6.1: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=772326

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216194

Comment: @marco how i do this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules